# print UInt8MultiArray values in python

Tags: python, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
Hi! I would like to save into 3 arrays the fields of a custum message:

std_msgs/UInt8MultiArray  pixel
std_msgs/Float64MultiArray nord
std_msgs/Float64MultiArray est
```

this is my callback to listen to the message. When I try to print pixel I get letters. How could I transform them to integers from 0 to 255? thanks

```
 def callback(data):
        #rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + "I heard %s", data.pixel.data)
        #rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + "I heard %s", data.est.data)
        #rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + "I heard %s", data.nord.data)
        pixel= np.array(data.pixel.data)
        print(pixel)
        est = np.array(data.est.data)
        nord= np.array(data.nord.data)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393396/print-uint8multiarray-values-in-python/) by [v.leto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37009/v.leto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 44 on 2021-12-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-27**:
Hi @v.leto can you please post what you get? Is it hexadecimal values?

**Comment by [v.leto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37009/v.leto/) on 2021-12-27**:
Hi @osilva!

```
 print(pixel)
```

outputs

```
hcc`hda`dadhgcfc_bcccaacaacebfdhfcifggadfhhbihiffcgfddbeafbceacfgbfbdcgfddebab_`da_bccfgeb`ceedce`dac`fad`bcbcacfaddcacdfchbcafecibhchcfefjifgaddfggdieeg`cdffgdgfjhdgbdedjdhdfdegcfddd`eb`fecehjefdhhdcfcdcdhicdbbhbadgchgfijggiehflikpikighhffhhgchdeccdegfhbda`badaecdgdedb`adbcbc``dgiggd`ceegcbbhbhdbbadccdbbbaaahgggfedgdefddecbifffciijiefbgchfeffgaddfeefbddcdcbdecacaaabcce`ededdeafcdaabaaaed`fade`cb`c^^_bbbeba`_dcbcb``cddcdffdfgddhlggjjnlimlijh
```

they are numbers from 0 to 255 but they are stored like strings

**Comment by [v.leto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37009/v.leto/) on 2021-12-27**:
I have read that it is a base64 because uint8[] are converted by rosbridge to base64,...

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-27**:
Ok then use this tutorial to decode: https://stackabuse.com/encoding-and-decoding-base64-strings-in-python/

```
import base64

base64_message = 'UHl0aG9uIGlzIGZ1bg=='
base64_bytes = base64_message.encode('ascii')
message_bytes = base64.b64decode(base64_bytes)
message = message_bytes.decode('ascii')

print(message)
```

Should `Python is fun`

**Comment by [v.leto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37009/v.leto/) on 2021-12-28**:
Your code works. I tried to modify mine in order to look like yours but I get errors. I used an online decorder and I think  my sting is not base64 as it doesn't end with ==.
my string· `eehggehhdeagefhfddbcadbecbcdcdaciffabbfchaaddbdcecafabbedecccececdbfdehhfibcaabfddcgegaabacddfcbcbfeedfdccd`dccf`bag`dfceceddad`cefhggbfjde`bicfggffddfcgcefhehcddfchdgcfacdb`fegfifgdahceidiehjjghhddafhgdaggegaefkihngihhejifehjikjdkgjgighechgehde`dcb`dadddaddccfcdebdcacbcacafddecdadbacedbbadbcbc`a`bbccgdbfgdebekifidghdegbehfhfdfgihigifbcighidc`dcbefcccgceaddcfhdhfbdbbcdehddcccfddbceaecacbbb`bfegidfbfddbd`cfdegfchfeaeeidcbccgfbh``efcfgdhkhhhjimkkhffiljjnlhmgicbfeffgeefdbeggfdbaegfdeidcbfdhdjiihdhhhcc`dihfhifahehgdehhigjihhllemmlimgfjwrfmlnliflldbcfiijfhhhaehhhlmllqoqojlmnkfllorrqstgnirqmejppnkhqmjiijildghgehdihjnnnlkfklkkhiiaffgmkgejijhdihhhkefgddjklihjoqfnnqiimqmomnlnlikhedcgfhgjkihgighfhjfkikkhghmohhhacghehfeeghlkihdgfieh`cfddbachchcabadeeegedffdejkhkmrmpqslnkolrrsklqpxtsqpxsuyxxrqpprurrmqrslnifklckpk`

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-28**:
Hi @v.leto, take a look at this discussion as there is more to the conversion that I thought: https://github.com/gramaziokohler/roslibpy/issues/38

```
pil_img = Image.fromarray(img)
buff = BytesIO()
pil_img.save(buff, format="JPEG")
new_image_string = base64.b64encode(buff.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! Thank you very much for your interest @osilva. I finally found a solution...and maybe it was easier than what I thought:

```
 pixel =data.pixel.data
 x=[ord(c) for c in pixel]
```

gives you a list in x that can be used in python

---

Originally posted by [v.leto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37009/v.leto/) with karma: 44 on 2021-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-28**:
Glad you found the answer.